# How to this without repeating code? Xamarin - Android

Tags: android, button, xamarin

i don't want to repeat this code all times:

```
Button btnClicks = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
Button btnWarning = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ButtonWarning);
```

How i can improve this code to look more clean?
This spam of code can really affect the performance of the application?

```
 protected override void OnResume()
    {          
        base.OnResume();
        Button btnClicks = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        Button btnWarning = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ButtonWarning);

        btnWarning.Click += btnWarn;
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        Button btnClicks = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        Button btnWarning = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ButtonWarning);

        btnWarning.Click -= btnWarn;

    }

    private void btnWarn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnWarning = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ButtonWarning);
        btnWarning.Text = string.Format("Warning Test");
    }
```

Comment: Use a Button member of the class and initialize it in the onCreate and then reuse it after?

Comment: Use member variables / fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the buttons class variables and then in `OnCreate`:

```
Button btnClicks;
Button btnWarning; 

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate(bundle);
   btnClicks = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
   btnWarning = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ButtonWarning); 
   btnWarning.Click += btnWarn;
}
```

now,

```
private void btnWarn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   btnWarning.Text = string.Format("Warning Test");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i know but if i try this:
protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            btnWarning.Click += btnWarn;
        }
I get an error Message: The name 'btnWarning' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Just doing in oncreate in enough, you don't have to do it in onresume and onpause.It will be triggered whenever you click the button

Comment: Oh NICE, after you edited your answer It just start works, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to remove the `Click` handler on pause?

It is usually enough to initialize the handler in `OnCreate` and that's it.

If you do need to access views more than once, then keep a reference to the view in the `Activity` class itself:

```
class MyActivity : Activity
{
  Button myButton;

  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
  {
     base.OnCreate(bundle);
     var myButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
  }

  protected override void OnPause()
  {
    // do something with myButton
  }
}
```

Comment: I  don't know if i really need to do it. Im doing this cause of OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: The memory problem is probably not related (at least according to the code you published)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you subscribe to an event, you should unsubscribe as well to release any memory resources attached to the activity. If you don´t unsubscribe, you may get `OutOfMemoryException` eventually. Actually, you were doing that part correctly, but as others mentioned, you need to use `OnCreate` to find views just once:

```
Button btnClicks;
Button btnWarning; 

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate(bundle);

   btnClicks = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
   btnWarning = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ButtonWarning); 
}

protected override void OnResume()
{          
    base.OnResume();

    btnWarning.Click += btnWarn;
}

protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();

    btnWarning.Click -= btnWarn;
}
```